# Is it possible for a specific unit / desktop to be unable to execute ofstream?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, ofstream

So I am a second year computer science student and tinkering with a personal project as a practice before our school activity. I am trying to be familiar with the fstream header. Now, I (or my computer / compiler) has no problem with ifstream. I can read contents of my text files just fine. My problem is with ofstream. It can't create or open text files. The .is_open function always returns false. Here's a copy of a part of my code.

```
void save() {

        fstream pData;
        pData.open("./files/characters.txt");

        if (!pData.is_open()){
            cout << "can't access / make file";
        }

        pData << flush;
        pData.close();
    }
```

Everytime I run my code the if statement will return true, which means the file is not created or cannot be opened. I thought I only had a problem on that project only, so I tried making another file with a new ofstream code. It didn't work. I also tried copying working ofstream codes online but it still didn't work on my pc. Am using Code::Blocks 20.03. Please help T^T

Comment: Are you sure your output directory has write rights? Side note : just use std::ofstream and open directly from the constructor.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Does the current directory of where the executable program is located have a `files` folder? Note that `fstream` will not create the folder for you if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Another small side note : stop using `using namespace std;`. This will become important in larger projects. (Watch this [episode of C++ weekly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZqjl9HEPZ8) if you want to know more)

Comment: One other issue is your question is asking about using `ofstream`, but your sample code uses `fstream` instead. Please clarify.

Comment: [What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/whats-the-problem-with-using-namespace-std)

Comment: Yet another small side note: take bigger "steps" and let objects do the work for you; instead of the four steps "declare, open, flush, close", you can just `ofstream pData("./files/characters.txt");` and the constructor and destructor will do the rest correctly and never forget. (And prefer `ifstream` and `ofstream` over `fstream`.)

Comment: Am sorry for updating this prob so late, i fixed it, and it's just avast blocking my code into making a file